# overflow auto not working on iOS

Tags: html, ios, css, overflow

I tried on many browsers, Firefox, Safari, IE10, Android devices, all working fine. But when it turns into iOS devices, like iPads, iPhones, the overflow is not working.

the structure is similar at the following:

```
<div class="slide-open-info"> <!-- this one has the overflow -->
    <p></p>
    <ul></ul>
    <!-- and more code -->
</div>

.slide-open-info {
    position: absolute;
    top: 130px;
    left: 0;
    width: 60vw;
    bottom: 0;
    overflow: auto;
    display: block;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}
```

The parent of this CSS has absolute position, with the height 100% of the window of the browser (it's a fullscreen website).

I have been searching why is not working, and found many answers to use `-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;` along with `overflow: auto;` but it's not working. I even tried `overflow: scroll;`, but nothing is happening.

Comment: I think the trick is to use both of these **together**: `-webkit-overflow-scrolling:touch;overflow: scroll;` - Have you tried that?

Comment: Just tested it, not working

Comment: Worked for me, though HTML in my case differs a lot. However this is frustrating — suddenly a standard style rule doesn't work, and a proprietary style rule has to be applied, even though it targets another thing. Also, it should be combined with a second rule. Like we're back in 2005.